# How to unit test Singleton class - C++?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

What are the ways to unit test a Singleton pattern in C++? (with examples please)

Comment: This looks like two rather separate questions. Maybe you could move the dependency injection part into a new question?

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche Dependency injection is said to be a way of unit testing, isn't it?

Comment: "Injecting a singleton into ..." and "unit testing a singleton" are two different subjects.

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche The link says that "Dependency injection is said to be a way of unit testing,", is it wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is so bad about Singletons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)

Comment: @AnishaKaul: That's not what the question originally asked, and I can't remove my vote now you've changed it. Anyway, that question does provide useful information about how difficult it is to unit test something that's inherently untestable.

Comment: Why have you editing this question so much it bears no relation to the original question - and you have started another question in a similar vain?

Comment: I really like this https://helpercode.com/2015/09/16/how-to-fake-a-singleton-in-c/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make the implementation of the singleton a separate class, and make a wrapper that implements the "singletonness" outside. That way you can test the implementation as much as you like (except the singleton behavior which is trivial and unnecessary.

```
class SingletonImpl {
public:
  int doit(double,double);
};

class Singleton {
public:
  Singleton& instance() {...}
  int doit(double a,double b) {impl->doit(a,b);}
  ...
private:
  SingletonImpl impl;
}
```

Comment: https://helpercode.com/2015/09/16/how-to-fake-a-singleton-in-c/ liked this better

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we have the classic singleton anti-pattern, which is responsible for three things:

```
class Singleton {
public:
    // Globally accessible instance
    static Singleton & instance();

    // Public interface
    void do_something();

private:
    // Lifetime management
    Singleton();
    ~Singleton();
}
```

and a class that depends on this:

```
class Dependent {
public:
    Dependent() : s(Singleton::instance()) {}

    void do_something_else();

private:
    Singleton & s;
};
```

Now we would like to write a unit test for the singleton:

```
void test_singleton() {
    Singleton s;        // Problem 1
    s.do_something();
    assert(/* some post-condition */);
}
```

and for the dependent class:

```
struct StubSingleton : Singleton // Problem 2
{
    int did_something;

    StubSingleton : did_something(0) {}
    void do_something() {++did_something;}    
};

void test_dependent() {
    StubSingleton s;    // Problem 1
    Dependent d(s);     // Problem 3
    d.do_something_else();
    assert(s.did_something == 1);
}
```

We see there are three problems to overcome:

1. We can't create and destroy instances during the tests;
2. We can't define our own subclasses to test how the interface is used;
3. We can't provide our own dependency to the dependent class.

The easiest way to overcome these problems is to refactor the singleton class:

1. Make the constructor and destructor public, moving responsibility for lifetime management out of the class;
2. Make the interface abstract, allowing us to define our own implementations;
3. Remove the global instance, and modify dependent classes to take its dependency by reference.

So now our classes look like:

```
class Singleton {
public:
    virtual ~Singleton() {}
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
};

class RealSingleton : public Singleton
{
    void do_something();
};

class Dependent {
public:
    explicit Dependent(Singleton & s) : s(s) {}
    void do_something_else();
private:
    Singleton & s;
};
```

Now the class is easy to test, and almost as easy to use in production (you just need to create an instance of `RealSingleton` and pass references to it where they're needed). The only problem is that you can't call it a singleton any more.

Comment: I'll follow up soon, here and on your other answer. Thanks.

Comment: In the code example the line:
StubSingleton : did_something(0) {}
Should actually be :
StubSingleton() : did_something(0) {} // Problem 1
Because the singleton constructor is inaccessible

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it

```
class Singleton
{
    protected:
       static Singleton *instance = 0:
    public:
       Singleton &GetInstance()
       {
          if (!instance) instance = new Singleton;
          return *instance;
       }
       ...
};
```

Then to test I would create just for testing purposes

```
class TestSingleton : public Singleton
{
     public:
        void DestroyInstance() {
           if (instance) delete instance;
           instance = 0;
};
```

Then use TestSingleton - so you are able to perform all the test cases and ensure that are the start the instance is recreated.

Comment: You didn't create the private constructor?

Comment: That is the '...' bit - I assumed you could fill in those bits.

Comment: I thought that was deliberate from you.

Answer (score 1):

A singleton is just a class of which you can only have one instance. How you find that instance is not part of that pattern, so using DI with a singleton is completely fine.

Unit-testing the singleton-pattern is hard, that is one of the main argument against using it. One way to do it in C++ is to have the definition of the singleton in a separate compilation unit, so that you can link against a mock-implementation when testing classes that use the singleton.